# javascript: want to resize window but also check if its open or closed

Tags: javascript, resize, window

why doesnt this work?

//I removed the 'for loops' for a second and then the script does something, what wrong with the loops?//

```
var openWindows= new Array[50]();

function resize(x){
```

//changed boolean to var
     var open = false;

```
 for(var i = 0; i < openWindows.length; i++){
  if(openWindows[i] == x){
   open = true;
   openWindows[i] = "";
  }
 }

 if(open == false){
  for(var i = 0; i < openWindows.length; i++){
   if(openWindows[i] == ""){
    openWindows[i] = x;
    break;
   }
  }

  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='200px'",20);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='220px'",40);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='240px'",60);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='260px'",80);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='280px'",100);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='300px'",120);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='320px'",140);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='340px'",160);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='360px'",180);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='380px'",200);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='400px'",220);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='420px'",240);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='440px'",260);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='460px'",280);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='480px'",300);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='500px'",320);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='520px'",340);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='540px'",360);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='560px'",380);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='580px'",400);
 }else{
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='560px'",40);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='540px'",60);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='520px'",80);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='500px'",100);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='480px'",120);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='460px'",140);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='440px'",160);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='420px'",180);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='400px'",200);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='380px'",220);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='360px'",240);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='340px'",160);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='320px'",260);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='300px'",280);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='280px'",300);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='260px'",320);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='240px'",340);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='220px'",360);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='200px'",380);
  var t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + x + "').style.height='180px'",400);
 }
}
```

Comment: Cause it's ugly. :) (Sorry for subjective negative comment)

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear enough what your code is supposed to do, but I can see a few issues.

The first line has a syntax error:

```
var openWindows= new Array[50]();  // Should be `Array(50)`
```

Javascript is a dynamically typed language, you do not need to assert types when declaring variables:

```
 boolean open = false;

 // Should be
 var open = false;
```

You should only use the `var` keyword once for each variable declaration.  In this case, every time you declare `var t = window.setTimeout(...);` you're redeclaring the variable.  In fact, you don't need the `var t =` at all.

Also, you can check to see if a window is closed using the `.closed` property:

```
if (windowVar.closed == true) { /* ... */ };
```

Comment: It's not a like a window window. It's more like a div acting a window. Changed boolean into var, but the script still doesn't work :(

Comment: I removed the 'for loops' for a second and then the script does something, what wrong with the loops?

Comment: @Jay, there doesn't appear to be anything syntactically wrong with the loops.

Comment: I see the error now. I declared the array in a wrong way :P
var openstaandeVensters = new Array[100];